# cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator) even with default constructor present

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a class that looks like

```
class MyClass {
    private byte[] payload;

    public MyClass(){}

    @JsonCreator
    public MyClass(@JsonProperty("payload") final byte[] payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public byte[] getPayload() {
        return this.payload;
    }

}
```

I am using Jackson so serialize and then to deserialize. Serialization works fine, but during deserialization, I am getting this error message -

```
Cannot construct instance of `mypackage.MyClass` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

I was reading about this problem online, and came across several texts recommending to have a default constructor or a constructor with `@JsonCreator` annotation. I tried adding both, but still getting that exception. What am I missing here?

Comment: I tested [like this](https://github.com/haba713/jackson-databind-test/blob/master/src/main/java/Main.java) with Jackson 2.9.7 and also deserialization worked fine.

Comment: You also need to have setters for every field.

Answer (score 24):

**EDIT:**

I just found a much better solution, add the [ParanamerModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/tree/master/paranamer) to the `ObjectMapper`:

```
mapper.registerModule(new ParanamerModule());
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-paranamer</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The advantage against the [ParameterNamesModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names) seems to be that the classes do not need to be compiled with the `-parameters` argument.

**END EDIT**

---

With Jackson 2.9.9 I tried to deserialize this simple POJO and came accros the same exception, adding a default constructor solved the problem:

**POJO:**

```
public class Operator {

    private String operator;

    public Operator(String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }
}
```

**ObjectMapper and Serialize/Deserialize:**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, Visibility.ANY);

String value = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Operator("test"));
Operator result = mapper.readValue(value, Operator.class);
```

**JSON:**

```
{"operator":"test"}
```

**Exception:**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
Cannot construct instance of `...Operator` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"operator":"test"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

**Solution (POJO with default constructor):**

```
public class Operator {

    private String operator;

    private Operator() {
    }

    public Operator(String operator) {
        this();
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the paranamer module does not solve the issue of jackson not being able to create the object due to the lack of an empty constructor. Tested with paranamer 2.12.2

Comment: your solution is forbidding final properties becauase of jackson. urg.

Comment: what happens if the class is a third class api that you cannot change?

Answer (score 17):

I observed this same issue. My issue was caused by me using the *wrong* JsonCreator type. I incorrectly used **org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonCreator**, but should have used **com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator** instead.

Answer (score 13):

I got this error and I tried https://newbedev.com/no-creators-like-default-construct-exist-cannot-deserialize-from-object-value-no-delegate-or-property-based-creator

Basically added

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

decorators and it worked for me.

Comment: in my case using only `@Data` was sufficient. I fixed the error by removing `final` keywords from the fields.

Answer (score 8):

In your subclass object add default constructor:

```
public NameOfClass() {
    super();
}
```

Comment: `@Data` (which adds `@RequiredArgsConstructor`) indeed wasn't sufficient. I had to make the property non-`final` and add a `@NoArgsConstructor`

Answer (score 5):

I came across this serializing and deserializing `kotlin data classes`. All I had to do was add default values for my properties and then reading the values worked.

```
data class DataClass(
  val key: String = "",    //  adding these default 
  val value: String = ""   //  values worked
)
```

without the `= ""`, I would get the error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `com.xxx.DataClass` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and none of the above solutions helped. After discovering debug builds worked fine, R8 was to blame because it was stripping some code needed by Jackson in release builds. Adding `@JsonAutoDetect` to all the custom class dependencies resolved the bug.

```
@JsonAutoDetect
data class Car(
    val name: String // annotation not needed
    val engine: Engine // annotation needed
)
// @JsonAutoDetect is needed here
data class Engine(
    val name: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing to the same, in my case i was in the statement to consume REST API  in Java...  but after  multiple attempts i was founding that i need to add the default Constructor because  i had already declared constructor with the fields..

```
public NameofClass() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please improvise your comments by giving code snippets clear

Answer (score 0):

Same story in Kotlin as I am testing with `MockMvc`, I had to go back to my data classes for RequestBody and Response to have default values, and imitate default constructors.

```
data class IntBodyPayload(val key: String = ""): Serializable
data class IntBodyResponse(val value: Int = 0): Serializable
```